# Play CORS not working

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.6

I have locally deployed my Play app and accessing my REST API via `localhost:9000` from within my browser works perfectly.

However, I get the following error when executing a jQuery script (see below) from `file:///C:/Users/XXX/XXX//index.html`:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

I followed the instructions given under https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/CorsFilter.

My `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  evolutions,
  guice,
  "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.194",
  javaJpa,
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-core" % "5.2.5.Final",
  filters
)
```

My `application.conf`:

```
play.filters.enabled += "play.filters.cors.CORSFilter"   

play.filters.cors {
  # allow all paths
  pathPrefixes = ["/"]
  # allow all origins (You can specify if you want)
  allowedOrigins = null
  allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"]
  # allow all headers
  allowedHttpHeaders = null
 }
```

NOTE: I tried both `allowedOrigins = null` & `allowedOrigins = ["*"]`

jQuery-script:

```
$.ajax({

    'url' : 'http://localhost:9000/employee/' + user_id + '/weeklyWorkingHours',
    'type' : 'GET',
    'success' : function(data) {
        console.log('Data: '+ JSON.stringify(data));

    },
    'error' : function(request,error)
    {
        console.log("Error: "+JSON.stringify(request));
    }
});
```

Here is what Play says:

```
[warn] p.f.c.CORSFilter - Invalid CORS request;Origin=Some(null);Method=GET;Access-Control-Request-Headers=None
```

Comment: Play specification says that `by default all origins are allowed`. You mention that you tried both `allowedOrigins = null` & `allowedOrigins = ["*"]`. Have you tried to remove it?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately it does not do the trick.

Comment: I think the problem is in here `Origin=Some(null)`. Play will validate this as `isValidOrigin = new URI("null").getScheme ne null`. Which returns false. Can you try to do the request with a valid `Origin`? This is `Origin = <some valid url>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to get CORS to work from a local file. The browser sends an `origin` header value of null to the server, and Play won't respond with an `access-control-allow-origin` header. For testing, you can set up a local web server, for example with

```
cd c:\Users\XXX\XXX
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Then you can load your file as

http://localhost:8000/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Isn't it possible to configure Play in such a way that null values are accepted as well? I think CORS is still not working as supposed because with a chrome plugin for CORS (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi), I can call localhost from a local file.

Comment: I have not found a way to configure Play like that and I read through enough source code that I don't think there is a provision for it. That extension does not modify the `origin` header, so you won't have happiness with Play. Be sure to monitor that header with the dev tools. Try the local web server.

Answer (score 2):

try to put this in application.conf (it will allow all origins)

```
play.filters.cors.allowedOrigins = null
```

and don't disable cors filter

```
play.filters.enabled += "play.filters.cors.CORSFilter"
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not solve the issue. Anyway thanks!

Comment: okay then  play.filters.cors.allowedOrigins = ["http://localhost:9000"]

Comment: Does not work neither because I am accessing my REST service from a different domain

Comment: just fill it with different domains play.filters.cors.allowedOrigins = ["localhost:9000" , "domain2.com", "domain3.com"]

Comment: Isn't there a way to accept all domains? In my project setup I won't be able to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. Now I don't get the same error anymore. I have updated my post. Do you have any further suggestions? I do not understand why it is still not working. I did exactly the same what was shown in the documentation.

Comment: try  `... 'type': 'GET',  beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Origin', '*')}, 'success' ...` in your ajax call

Comment: this approach did work on play 2.6.10. so, thumbs up

Answer (score 1):

Because I spent way too much time on this, here's the answer in Java for Play 2.12:

1. in app\filters\CorsFilter.java:

   ```
   package filters;

   import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;
   import java.util.function.Function;

   import com.google.inject.Inject;
   import com.google.inject.Singleton;

   import akka.stream.Materializer;
   import play.mvc.Filter;
   import play.mvc.Http.RequestHeader;
   import play.mvc.Result;



   @Singleton
   public class CorsFilter extends Filter {

       @Inject
       public CorsFilter(Materializer mat) {
        super(mat);
       }

       @Override
       public CompletionStage<Result> apply(Function<RequestHeader, CompletionStage<Result>> next, RequestHeader rh) {

        return next.apply(rh).thenApply(result ->
            {
                return result.withHeaders(
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" , "*",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" , "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" , "Accept, Content-Type, Origin, X-Json, X-Prototype-Version, X-Requested-With",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" , "true"
                    );
            });
       }
   ```

   }
2. in your conf\application.conf, add the following line somewhere:

   ```
   play.filters.enabled += filters.CorsFilter
   ```
3. in your conf\routes, add the following:

   ```
   OPTIONS    /          controllers.OptionsController.options(path: String ?= "")
   OPTIONS    /*path     controllers.OptionsController.options(path)
   ```
4. add class controllers.OptionsController (in app\controllers\OptionsController.java):

   ```
   package controllers;

   import play.mvc.Controller;
   import play.mvc.Result;

   public class OptionsController extends Controller {

    public Result options(String path) {

        return ok("").withHeaders(
                  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" , "*",
                  "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" , "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
                  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" , "Accept, Origin, Content-type, X-Json, X-Prototype-Version, X-Requested-With",
                  "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" , "true",
                  "Access-Control-Max-Age" , Integer.toString(60 * 60 * 24)
        );
    }
   }
   ```